# Kubernetes Failed Scheduling : Pending Pod

Tags: kubernetes

I get this error:
`FailedScheduling  40s (x3 over 11m)  default-scheduler  0/6 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/6 nodes are available: 6 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling..`

It comes from here :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get pods -l="app=cassandra"
NAME          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cassandra-0   0/1     Pending   0          10m

root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl describe pod cassandra-0
Name:             cassandra-0
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             <none>
Labels:           app=cassandra
                  apps.kubernetes.io/pod-index=0
                  controller-revision-hash=cassandra-95df4dff4
                  statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=cassandra-0
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Pending
IP:               
IPs:              <none>
Controlled By:    StatefulSet/cassandra
Containers:
  cassandra:
    Image:       gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v13
    Ports:       7000/TCP, 7001/TCP, 7199/TCP, 9042/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Limits:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      500m
      memory:   1Gi
    Readiness:  exec [/bin/bash -c /ready-probe.sh] delay=15s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE:           512M
      HEAP_NEWSIZE:            100M
      CASSANDRA_SEEDS:         cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local
      CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME:  K8Demo
      CASSANDRA_DC:            DC1-K8Demo
      CASSANDRA_RACK:          Rack1-K8Demo
      POD_IP:                   (v1:status.podIP)
    Mounts:
      /cassandra_data from cassandra-data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-8fkm9 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False 
Volumes:
  cassandra-data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  cassandra-data-cassandra-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-8fkm9:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Guaranteed
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  40s (x3 over 11m)  default-scheduler  0/6 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/6 nodes are available: 6 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling..
```

All nodes are `Ready` :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get nodes
NAME                STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
k8s-eu-1-master     Ready    control-plane   43h   v1.28.2
k8s-eu-1-worker-1   Ready    <none>          20h   v1.28.2
k8s-eu-1-worker-2   Ready    <none>          20h   v1.28.2
k8s-eu-1-worker-3   Ready    <none>          20h   v1.28.2
k8s-eu-1-worker-4   Ready    <none>          20h   v1.28.2
k8s-eu-1-worker-5   Ready    <none>          20h   v1.28.2
```

I've put output of `kubectl describe node` for each of the 6 nodes, in a txt file, because `StackOverFlow` does not accept more than 30k characters in a post:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ONtdbjn-OI6bzRQVSpExdsb73Q8JcnXC/view?usp=sharing

And, I do not see any issues with memory and / or cpu

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get pvc
NAME                         STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
cassandra-data-cassandra-0   Pending                                      fast           6h3m
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# 
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get pv
No resources found
```

As `headless Service` and `StatefulSet` configurations I've used the ones found here : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/cassandra/

root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# cat ./Cassandra/cassandra-service.yaml
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/cassandra/#creating-a-cassandra-headless-service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: cassandra
  name: cassandra
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 9042
  selector:
    app: cassandra


root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# cat ./Cassandra/cassandra-statefulset.yaml 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: cassandra
  labels:
    app: cassandra
spec:
  serviceName: cassandra
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cassandra
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cassandra
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 1800
      containers:
      - name: cassandra
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v13
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 7000
          name: intra-node
        - containerPort: 7001
          name: tls-intra-node
        - containerPort: 7199
          name: jmx
        - containerPort: 9042
          name: cql
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: 1Gi
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add:
              - IPC_LOCK
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: 
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - nodetool drain
        env:
          - name: MAX_HEAP_SIZE
            value: 512M
          - name: HEAP_NEWSIZE
            value: 100M
          - name: CASSANDRA_SEEDS
            value: "cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local"
          - name: CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME
            value: "K8Demo"
          - name: CASSANDRA_DC
            value: "DC1-K8Demo"
          - name: CASSANDRA_RACK
            value: "Rack1-K8Demo"
          - name: POD_IP
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: status.podIP
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
            - /ready-probe.sh
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        # These volume mounts are persistent. They are like inline claims,
        # but not exactly because the names need to match exactly one of
        # the stateful pod volumes.
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cassandra-data
          mountPath: /cassandra_data
  # These are converted to volume claims by the controller
  # and mounted at the paths mentioned above.
  # do not use these in production until ssd GCEPersistentDisk or other ssd pd
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: cassandra-data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: fast
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: fast
provisioner: k8s.io/minikube-hostpath
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
```

`minikube addon for the hostpath provisioning` :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get sc -o wide
NAME   PROVISIONER                RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
fast   k8s.io/minikube-hostpath   Delete          Immediate           false                  6h17m
```

Update 1)

I cleaned up the cassandra deployment (service and statefulset) with : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/cassandra/#cleaning-up

I commented in `cassandra-statefulset.yaml` the `StorageClass` part :

```
#kind: StorageClass
#apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
#metadata:
  #name: fast
#provisioner: k8s.io/minikube-hostpath
#parameters:
  #type: pd-ssd
```

I then created again the headless Service :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl apply -f ./Cassandra/cassandra-service.yaml 
service/cassandra created
```

And the Cassandra ring:

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get pods -l="app=cassandra"
NAME          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cassandra-0   0/1     Pending   0          3m14s

root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get sc -o wide
NAME   PROVISIONER                RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
fast   k8s.io/minikube-hostpath   Delete          Immediate           false                  6h39m
```

How to make it work?

Comment: You are missing a persistent volume claim. Show output of `kubectl get pvc` and `kubectl get pv`

Comment: Hi @Thomas ! Thanks for helping. I've updated my post above with the info about persistent volume claim. `kubectl get pvc` -> `NAME                         STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
cassandra-data-cassandra-0   Pending                                      fast           6h3m
` .  `kubectl get pv` -> `No resources found`

Comment: check if you have enabled the minikube addon for the hostpath provisioning. A quicker way might be to check the storageclasses `kubectl get sc -o wide` and use the default storage class which should be auto provisioned on minikube.

Comment: @Thomas Updated with this info my post above

Comment: That StorageClass looks suspicious to me – it seems like you're explicitly requesting a specific kind of Minikube storage, but Minikube isn't usually a 6-node cluster.  Does deleting the StorageClass object and the `storageClassName` reference in the StatefulSet help?

Comment: @DavidMaze I cleaned up the cassandra deployment, I commented in cassandra-statefulset.yaml the StorageClass part, then created again the headless Service and Cassandra Ring. But the issue persists. I updated my post above with Update 1)

Answer (score 0):

A Persistent Volume Claim (PVC) is not being fulfilled, which is why the PVC says `pending`.  And why your `kubectl get pv` is returning no resources.

A PVC needs to be able to get a PV in order for your node to start.

The relationship between a PVC and a node is like:

```
Pod --> PVC --> PV
```

In your case it looks like the PV is a host path. As one commenter said, you should check to make sure this Storage Class is working. The `sc` is sort of the driver for handling a PVC.

---

On a broader note:

Due to the somewhat complicated deployment charcteristics of Cassandra on k8s, I would highly recommend using this k8s Operator to manage Cassandra:
https://github.com/k8ssandra/cass-operator

Bear in mind, running Cassandra on minikube (not sure that's even possible) is going to be a somewhat poor simulation of how Cassandra is going to behave, since Cassandra is fundamentally designed to be a highly available storage back end. In order to get a feel for what will work in production its very important to run Cassandra on multiple pods on multiple nodes, even in development - since the entire point of Cassandra is high availability and scale. Otherwise I would just swap out your data storage for local development using some trivial kv store given that you have some kind of key-value shim code.

Comment: Thank you. Since I do actually need Cassandra for its high availability and scale, I need to run it on multiple pods on multiple nodes. Even in Development. I'm going to try `k8s Operator`, but I would like understand the root cause of the issue I'm facing now